# How many total days are on the ledger?

Tags: monerod, blockchain

Is there a tool or a source that tells how many total days are currently on the ledger? I know that monerod tells how many days behind you are on the ledger, but is there an easy way to look up the total number of days without syncing up with the blockchain for the first time?

Edit: This may just need to be a feature request, but I am running a windows machine in this case and seeking a cross platform solution. I was hoping there is a built in argument to do something like the [following code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/c2a9229310672c38e44e46ad5b120fe2209a739c/src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl#L281) in monerod:

`LOG_PRINT_CCONTEXT_YELLOW("Sync data returned a new top block candidate: " << m_core.get_current_blockchain_height() << " -> " << hshd.current_height
<< " [Your node is " << std::abs(diff) << " blocks (" << ((abs(diff) - diff_v2) / (24 * 60 * 60 / DIFFICULTY_TARGET_V1)) + (diff_v2 / (24 * 60 * 60 / DIFFICULTY_TARGET_V2)) << " days) "`

Part of the output then is something like `Your node is 73520 blocks (102 days) behind`

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a UNIX-like OS such as Linux or macOS, and have [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed, you can do this:

`curl -s -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"getblock","params":{"height":1}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' | jq '.result.block_header.timestamp' | gawk '{print strftime("%c", $0)}'`

`Fri 18 Apr 2014 12:49:53`

The first part displays the genesis block in JSON format. The `jq`-filter, selects the "UNIX" timestamp (`1397818193`), which gets converted to a readable date and time with `gawk`.

Obviously, instead of `127.0.0.1`, you could point to any node, such as `node.moneroworld.com`. The RPC-call is described in the [Daemon RPC Documentation](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/daemon-rpc#getblock).

**Update:** I just realized you don't want the date, but the number of days since. The following one-liner, using `bc`, gives you the number of days:

`echo "scale = 1; ($(date +%s) - $(curl -s -X POST http://node.moneroworld.com:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"getblock","params":{"height":1}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' | jq '.result.block_header.timestamp')) / 86400" | bc`

`993.4`

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping a better answer is posted with a way to calculate this directly from the blockchain, but the first block listed at [moneroblocks](http://moneroblocks.info/browser/blocks/1) has a timestamp of `2014-04-18 10:49:53 UTC`.

I used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how+many+days+has+it+been+since+2014-04-18+10:49:53+UTC) to calculate it quickly and it shows 991.1 days at the time of this post.