# How to extract data from local blockchain

Tags: monerod, rpc, api

How to extract data, blocks from blockcain stored on local disk drive, and acquire it through some usual data transfer chanel (eg. JSON) in other application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run a local daemon, and then use the daemon RPC API to query it for blocks:

https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/daemon-rpc

Comment: Expanding on this answer, the `jq` utility is really handy to filter out the JSON output. To illustrate, have a look at [this example](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3253), which dealt with the date of the genesis block, and number of days on the blockchain.